# Cross-compile for PowerPC Linux in Windows environment

Tags: windows, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, powerpc, toolchain

Because of some constraints I will have to build Linux user space applications for PowerPC QorIQ (P1020) using Windows environment.

Has anyone tried it and could recommend some toolchain (working natively in Win 7)?

Using virtual machines for building applications is not acceptable. What can be done on VM is only kernel and rootfs preparation.
There are some toolchains like http://gnutoolchains.com/powerpc-eabi/ however they do not provide Linux libraries. I guess I need something like powerpc-fsl-linux-gcc.exe.
 I have also tried to attach meta-mingw layer to Yocto and bitbake meta-toolchain, but I'm not sure if it's the right path - I got many build errors.

Comment: You could try ELLCC: http://ellcc.org

Comment: Look in http://www.mingw.org/ land and see if there is a cross compiler there.

You could look at this for instance: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-gcc-powerpc-eabi/

Comment: I need to do the same thing. Did you find a way?